# touchpad not working on lenovo ideapad flex 5 14ABR8 when using linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, touchpad

when using kubuntu/latest debian/lubuntu/ a lenovo ideapad flex 5 14ABR8 the touchpad doesnt work. it is not listed under the devices for libinput. i have so far tried:

- installing `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics`. installed fine and did nothing.
- installing `xserver-xorg-input-libinput`. installed fine and did nothing.
- installing the `libinput` snap. installed fine and did nothing.
- installing `https://github.com/Syniurge/i2c-amd-mp2` installed fine and did nothing.
- enabling the touchpad in settings - it does not show up to enable in the first place.

is there anything else i can try? is this laptop impossible to get the touchpad working on?
any help (or just reasons why the touchpad will not show up) would be great

Answer (score 0):

Update 2: **My solution** was to downgrade to [5.19 arch kernel](https://archive.archlinux.org) and install [wifi+bluetooth drivers](https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be). **Everything is functional**, and yes this is on the IdeaPad Flex 5 14ABR8.

For Ubuntu, I haven't tested it, however I believe you can downgrade the kernel graphically using Mainline. [Installation:](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/how-to-downgrade-the-kernel-in-ubuntu/)

```
sudo apt-add-repository -y ppa:cappelikan/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mainline
```

Then launch Mainline, select the 5.19 kernel, install. If wifi/bluetooth is dysfunctional try installing the drivers mentioned earlier.

.

I first managed to make it work by reinstalling Ubuntu to version 18.04. However this was a *very* bad solution as the majority of apps that I use were not functional on such an old version.

obsolete links and references have been removed from this post.

as of 5.9.23 everything works by default on the latest arch kernel.

Comment: Link only answe is not acceptable. Please add mord details.

Comment: Re-wrote it a bit, should be better now